# How can I return a value from google app engine to jquery?

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine

After a user enters data on my home page, I wish to send the values to a google app engine python script for processing. When the script is done processing, I want it to pass the values back to my home page which will display the results on the lower part of the page. Since I don't want to reload the whole page, I want to use jquery when user hits submit.

I have 2 questions
1) How do I pass the results back to my home page from within python
2) In my $.ajax call, how do I specify the name of the python script which will handle the processing

```
jquery code
$(function() {  
  $("input#Submit").click(function() {  
    $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "/",  //my python script
  data: {
       var1: $("input#var1").val(),
       var2: $("input#var2").val()      
  },
  success: function(returnData){
    alert(returnData)
  }

});  
});

python script
class processInfo(webapp.RequestHandler):
    var1 = self.request.get("var1")
    var2 = self.request.get("var2")
    do some processing here e.g.
    var 3 = var1* var2
    how do i return var 3 back to the $.ajax call?

application = webapp.WSGIApplication( ('/', processInfo), debug = true)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `returnData` argument to the success function in your Javascript will be passed the body of the response to the HTTP request. Simply write the data you want with `self.response.out.write` in your handler.

Specifying what script to call is done the same as anywhere else: Map the handler in your WSGI app (in your sample, it's mapped as '/', which you probably don't want), and ensure the handler script is mapped correctly in app.yaml. Handling an AJAX call is no different to handling any other standard HTTP request.

Comment: I tried [self.response.out.write(var3)] but it replaces the whole html page i.e. it does not pass it to the success function of the jquery function

Comment: @Tolu It looks like you're attaching the event to the click event on the submit button on a form. If that's the case, in addition to your script running and doing an AJAX request, your browser will also perform a standard form submission, just as it would without Javascript. You should remove the action from the form, and make it a regular button, not a submit button.

Comment: Will try that. Another question - you said I shouldn't use the '/' mapping that I currently have. Right now, I'm testing on my local machine so the browser url is http://localhost:8081/. My intention is that when user lands on the default page of my server, it should display my form which is on the index.htm page. How should  I then do the WSGI app mapping?

Comment: @Tolu Map '/' to the handler that serves up the HTML page containing the javascript. Map some other URL to the Javascript AJAX request handler.